# Set some Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to set a working with Alarm manager. I want to start alarm manager in 11 a.m and after that call a stop alarm manager in 11:10 and again start alarm in 11:15 and continue like this. but i think not working my code. Do i need some Alarm manager object for some setting alarm?

what is my problem? Do you have any advise to me?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.managedatamenu_activity);

    am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    start(9,50);
    stop(9,52);
    start(9,53);
    stop(9,54);
    start(11,13);
    stop(11,15);

    //setAlarm();
    initItems();
}


private void start(int hour,int min){
    //First start
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Start","start");
    pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);
}

private void stop(int hour,int min){
    //First start
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Stop","stop");
    pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);
}
```

Comment: I guess you want something like **snooze** settings.Don't you?

Comment: I want to start my service for tracking user in specific time and stop service and not tracking user. for stop and start service in specific time, i used Alarm Manager. Do my approach is true?

Comment: The approach is right but trivial. There are however many ways to achieve the same objective

Comment: what is best approach for my objective?

Comment: and Why this approach not working and not calling all of alarms?